# Installing Bundler in Linux Mint

Tags: ruby, linux, bundler, linux-mint

I was trying to install bundler in Linux Mint. 
but I'm getting this error

```
$ gem install bundler 
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= > 0) in any repository
```

Tried to do

```
$ gem update --system
```

but this is not permitted in Debian based systems.

what to do??

Comment: How about using the package? http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/ruby-bundler

Comment: Linux mint is just an ubuntu, you should find more if you google for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run

> gem sources -a http://rubygems.org

Then run gem install